# Change value to show a different value based on current value

Tags: sql

I am having trouble thinking of a solution to what should be a rather simple problem;

if I do a;

```
SELECT *  
FROM Database
```

and it showed:

```
id | username | FName | LName   | ReportsTo | email  
---+----------+-------+---------+-----------+--------------------------------
1  | fgibbins | Frank | Gibbins | rleo      | fgibbins@fictionalcompany.com  
---+----------+-------+---------+-----------+--------------------------------
2  | rleo     | Roger | Leo     | null      | rleo@gictionalcompany.com
---+----------+-------+---------+-----------+--------------------------------
```

*What I would like is for whatever value in `ReportsTo` to show up as `FName` `LName`.*

What is the best way to accomplish this, how can I have it look at the username in ReportsTo show up as a full name?

Been a while since I worked with SQL, so I am trying to get this right.

Comment: Did you try `SELECT FName,LName FROM Database`?

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Why are you naming a _table_ "database"?

Comment: the table "database" was just an example, not saying that I named it Database, I simply said, you run a query and you get.... xxxxxx.... thats all I was showing there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to combine two column data you can use `CONCAT` function.

And self join your table.

I guess you want to do some like this.

```
SELECT t1.username,
       t1.Fname,
       t1.LName,
       CONCAT(t1.FName,' ',t1.LName,' reports to ',t2.FName,' ',t2.LName) ReportsTo
FROM [Database] t1
LEFT JOIN [Database] t2 ON t1.ReportsTo = t2.username
WHERE t2.username IS NOT NULL
```

*sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a0c1e/9*

Comment: This completely got my item working as I needed it. Thank you so much for your help! :D

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

If the fields you're handling are fixed, you can do

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    username, 
    FName, 
    LName, 
    FName + ' ' + LName AS ReportsTo, 
    email  
FROM Database
```

Comment: So I still want it to show all the values, but say, id 1, Frank Gibbins reports to id 2, Roger Leo, right now its only showing ReportsTo as RLeo, how can I get it to say Frank Gibbins reports to Roger Leo.

Comment: What If you try:
SELECT 
    d.id, 
    d.username, 
    d.FName, 
    d.LName, 
    rt.FName + ' ' + rt.LName AS ReportsTo, 
    d.email  
FROM Database d
    INNER JOIN Database rt ON d.ReportsTo = rt.username

Comment: That is invalid standard SQL. The string concatenation operator in SQL is `||` not `+` (which is used to add numbers).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, am I correct to say || is Oracle specific?

Comment: @PawelCz: no it's not Oracle specific `||` was defined in the SQL standard in 1986 as the operator to concatenate strings. Oracle (and Postgres and DB2 and Firebird and many others) do comply with the SQL standard and use correctly use `||`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, thnx, I am using sql-server so I wasn't aware about this way of concatenation...

Answer (score 0):

Try this (you can change the '' in the `IFNULL` to be 'Nobody' or something else if you prefer):

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.username, CONCAT(t1.FName,' ',t1.LName) AS name, IFNULL(CONCAT(t2.FName, ' ', t2.LName), '') AS ReportsTo, t1.email
FROM `database` t1
LEFT JOIN `database` t2 ON t1.ReportsTo = t2.username
```

Output:

```
id  username    name            ReportsTo   email
1   fgibbins    Frank Gibbins   Roger Leo   fgibbins@fictionalcompany.com
2   rleo        Roger Leo                   rleo@gictionalcompany.com
```